# Not able to understand the code in Matplot lib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I know that the following code plots a scatter plot, with its own markers. I am not able to understand the converter function.

The general defnition of converter function is :
A dictionary mapping column number to a function that will convert that column to a float. E.g., if column 0 is a date string: converters = {0: datestr2num}. Converters can also be used to provide a default value for missing data (but see also genfromtxt): converters = {3: lambda s: float(s.strip() or 0)}. Default: None.

But I am not able to understand what it does in following code; what does read_label function do??

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
label_list = (
b'Iris-setosa',
b'Iris-versicolor',
b'Iris-virginica',
)
def read_label(label):
   return label_list.index(label)

data = np.loadtxt('iris.data.txt', delimiter = ',', converters = { 4 : read_label })

marker_set = ('^', 'x', '.')

for i, marker in enumerate(marker_set):
  data_subset = numpy.asarray([x for x in data if x[4] == i])

plt.scatter(data_subset[:,0], data_subset[:,1], color = 'k', marker = marker)
plt.show()
```

The iris.data.txt file consists of following data :

4.6,3.2,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.3,3.7,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.3,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
7.0,3.2,4.7,1.4,Iris-versicolor
6.4,3.2,4.5,1.5,Iris-versicolor

Answer (score 1):

You can easily investigate the behavior of `read_label` with a tiny test program:

```
label_list = (
b'Iris-setosa',
b'Iris-versicolor',
b'Iris-virginica',
)

def read_label(label):
    return label_list.index(label)

print read_label("Iris-setosa")
print read_label("Iris-versicolor")
print read_label("Iris-virginica")
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
```

Alternatively you [look up Python's `index` method](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html): It returns the list index of the given element.

Note that you get a `ValueError` if you ask for an element not present in the list. You might want to use `find` in that case.

Comment: Ya I got it, But what does converters do here. I couldnt understand - converters = { 4 : read_label }

Comment: @user3796494: It tells the `loadtext` to apply `read_label` to column number 4. So each string in that column will be converted into the corresponding index in `label_list`.